# What does sgn mean?

Tags: notation

I am reading "space filling curve" by Hans Sagan. On page 17, on equation (2.3.11) in the equation, a function sgn is used.

What is sgn?

To put it into context, in the book it says $h_n=$sgn$(n)[(n-1)+i]$

Comment: It is a slightly abbreviated form of "sign" as in positive or negative.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Comment: The reason for abbreviation is a little clearer when calling it the signum function.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Typically, $\operatorname{sgn}$ stands for the sign function
$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \\ -1 & x < 0 \end{cases}.$$

Comment: NB the definitions of $\mathop{\rm sgn}(0)$ vary between $0$ and $1$. If $0$ is a plausible argument, you should assure yourself of the definition of $\mathop{\rm sgn}$ at $0$ in your context.

Comment: @AlexR Actually, they vary between three options: **(a)** $\operatorname{sgn}0=0$; **(b)** $\operatorname{sgn}0=1$; **(c)** $\operatorname{sgn}0$ is undefined, i.e., $\operatorname{Dom}\operatorname{sgn} = \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. I'm in favor of (a) and I consder (b) a deadly sin.

Comment: When $\text{sgn}(x)$ is used for applications (e.g., robust statistics), it is most commonly asserted that $\text{sgn}(0) = 0$ (as far as I know).

Comment: @yo, I guess it depends on whether or not the relationship between the sign function and the unit step function needs to be maintained, among other things.

Comment: @J.M. There is of course also a simple relationship with the unit step function $H(x)$ ($H$ stands for Heaviside) to the symmetric $\operatorname{sgn}$ function: $\operatorname{sgn}x=H(x)-H(-x)$. The relation you are alluding to with the asymmetric sign function is $\operatorname{sgn}^+x=2H(x)-1$.

Comment: I also encountered $\rm{sign}(0)={1\over 2}$ in a textbook.

Comment: @Karlo This seems strange. Are you sure it wasn't the heaviside function in your textbook?

Comment: @Dominik Sorry, my bad. That was the Heaviside function indeed. Wouldn't make a lot of sense with the signum function.

Comment: Hi everyone, I'm wondering about @user347499´s response, in which context does sgn(0) is undefined? I guess it's something like sgn(x) = |x| / x, I'm not sure (like d/dx |x|) is this right? But I'm not sure about when it should be considered undefined

Answer (score 1):

I will expand on Dominik's answer.

$ \operatorname{sgn} $, standing for "sign", is usually defined as,

$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \\ -1 & x < 0 \end{cases}.$$

**but** not always. Some use

$$\operatorname{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0 \\ 0 & x < 0 \end{cases}.$$

(that is, $ \operatorname{sgn}(0) $ is undefined).

In rare cases, one might define $ \operatorname{sgn}(0) $ as one or zero, for convinience. It really depends on the situation and usecase.